# BitTorrent speed drops out of no where?

Tags: networking, vpn, download, bittorrent, isp

I have BitTorrent (v7.9.9) installed on Windows 10. I have a 20Mbps fiber line, which means I should roughly be getting 2,5MBps. I understand my ISP will lower my speed if I'm constantly downloading and hogging their network bandwidth. I've downloaded torrents before at a speed of 1 to 2MBps, which is decent. for some reason, out of no where, my speed suddenly drops out of no where? As soon as I get to 2%, my speed drops from 1-2MBps to 0.5KBps and does not regain its old speed. It ALWAYS happens on 2%, which makes me think that its actually not my ISP throttling my network. Sometimes BitTorrent is fine and maintains 1-2MBps. I have tried using a VPN (Betternet VPN) and I've configured my Torrent client according to BitTorrent's guide. My browsing speed is fast and it is fast when I load websites. It seems like my download speed is the problem. I do understand that my ISP may throttle, but I've been using a VPN? Surely this should help? But the thing is, my download speed from the Internet is about 500-1MBps, whereas my Torrent speed is not even 500KBps, it's 0.5KBps? This doesn't always happen though. Sometimes the speed is full and other days its bad on my Torrent client. Can anyone help me as to why and how to stop this from happening. Thank you, I appreciate your help and time!

Comment: Your torrent download speed depends on the speeds offered by the uploaders you are connecting to...

Comment: Yeah I know that. But the thing is, it happens with more than one torrent and ALWAYS on 2%. As I said, this doesn't happen too often. However, now what I've done is once it gets to 2% and the speed drops, I've stopped the torrent, and then clicked start again and it seems perfectly fine afterwards.

Comment: You should ask you ISP if they are throttling your connection in any way (like assigning your traffic low priority), we cannot know that.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thank you for your response. I will pop them an email during the week asking.

Comment: I suspect it's the same reason as here: http://superuser.com/questions/1126041/torrent-huge-download-speed-fluctuations/1126088#1126088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many causes. Apart from your ISP (which we cannot say anything about), it can very well be a caching issue (if you're downloading torrents of roughy the same size, a cache is filled at roughly the same moment each time). E.g. here on an SSD, I experience a delay upon starting a large download because the disk is a bit slow at allocating a very large file all at once. Randomness in the delay occurrence may be caused by disk fragmentation - whether the torrent client was lucky to get a relatively continuous chunk.

Comment: Yeah, the download was 4.2GB. Thank you for your helping response!

Comment: @MarkPrescher If the answer resolved the issue, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.